What is a Kebab Word™?
Credit to JLee for starting this series of puzzles.
If a word conforms to a certain property, I call it a Kebab Word™. What is the rule that decides whether a word fits, and what is the purpose of the name?



Kebab Word™
Not Kebab Word™




operator
engineer


generic
bland


bargains
negotiations


fascinating
interesting


considerable
substantial


pilot
driver


conscious*
vigilant


bibliography*
citation


contribution**
improvement


kilometer**
fathom


instrumental**
key


distinguished**
composed


inspiration***
encouragement



*     Large kebab
**   Multi kebab
*** Family dinner
CSV for analysis:
operator,engineer
generic,bland
bargains,negotiations
fascinating,interesting
considerable,substantial
pilot,driver
conscious,vigilant
bibliography,citation
contribution,improvement
kilometer,fathom
instrumental,key
distinguished,composed
inspiration,encouragement

Hint 1:

 I have a nice set of metal kebab sticks, which are very resistant to bending.

Hint 2:

 I'm very picky with what I put in my kebabs. It's a terrible habit, since with most packs of meat I end up wasting a lot of food.

Hint 3 (Bigger one):

 Early in development, the name of the puzzle was "What is a Collinear Word™?" I changed it because, 1, that was slightly inaccurate, and 2, Kebab is more fun :D


can you say whether font and case matters? in other words, must they all be lower case, or does the property hold regardless of case and font?

@JLee Font and case are irrelevant. I chose lowercase just because I happened to be working with it in my code

And only trivial knowledge is needed right?

@Prim3numbah Yep, only trivial knowledge is needed. If you're going to Google to look something up, that's the wrong direction

Anything to do with your keyboard? Is "skepticism" (a word typed with alternating L and R keystrokes) a kebab word? Or odd number of consonant clusters (though that's heavily dependent on accent so idk)?

@Josh For this type of puzzle, if you have an idea you can test it out by seeing if your rule applies to all the words on the left and none of the ones on the right. If it passes that test, post it as an answer :)

I believe that Kebab words are defined as follows

 For a given word map each letter to a 2-dimensional point defined by
 (position in the word, position in the alphabet)
 If at least three points within this space are collinear then the word is a Kebab word.
 There is also an additional rule that the letters within the kebab must be equally spaced across the word (see note on the large kebab).

Examples

 The word GENERIC maps to the points (1,7), (2,5), (3,14), (4,5), (5,18), (6,9), (7,3) and three of the points here are collinear - (1,7), (4,5), (7,3).
 The word PILOT maps to (1,16), (2,9), (3,12), (4,15), (5,20) and three of the points here are collinear - (2,9), (3,12), (4,15).

Large kebabs

 I think are defined by having at least four collinear points.
CONSCIOUS maps to (1,3), (2,15), (3,14), (4,19), (5,3), (6,9), (7,15), (8,21), (9,19) which has the collinear points - (5,3), (6,9), (7,15), (8,21).
BIBLIOGRAPHY maps to (1,2), (2,9), (3,2), (4,12), (5,9), (6,15), (7,7), (8,18), (9,1), (10,16), (11,8), (12,25) which has the collinear points - (2,9), (4,12), (6,15), (8,18).
 Normally OPERATOR could also qualify as a large kebab, with the collinear points (1,15), (2,16), (4,18), (6,20). However, with the additional rule that the letters must be evenly spaced within the word, we would discard (1,15) and then this is just a Kebab word.

Multi kebab

 Is a word which has at least two sets of three collinear points which are not collinear as a union.
KILOMETER maps to (1,11), (2,9), (3,12), (4,15), (5,13), (6,5), (7,20), (8,5), (9,18) which has the collinear points (1,11), (3,12), (5,13) and another set (2,9), (3,12), (4,15).
DISTINGUISHED maps to (1,4), (2,9), (3,19), (4,20), (5,9), (6,14), (7,7), (8,21), (9,9), (10,19), (11,8), (12,5), (13,4) which has the collinear points (2,9), (7,7), (12,5) and (2,9), (6,14), (10,19).

Family dinner

 This describes words which are both large kebab and multi kebab.
INSPIRATION maps to (1,9), (2,14), (3,19), (4,16), (5,9), (6,18), (7,1), (8,20), (9,9), (10,15), (11,14) which has the collinear points (1,9), (5,9), (9,9) and (2,14), (4,16), (6,18), (8,20) which makes it both a large and a multi.

Author edit - here's a graph depicting the solution for the word 'instrumental':

 

Also, additional note:

 There are actually three Kebab lines in 'distinguished' and 'inspiration' as well. That's on me for not specifying though - I probably should have called them 'triple Kebabs' or something.


Congrats, that's it. And you're also right with OPERATOR - that's the inaccuracy I mentioned in the last hint.

@ApexPolenta ah, yes, I see

Graphs would be nice.  But good job on finding that answer!
